# Is it possible to inherit from a class which is recursively generated?

Tags: c#, inheritance, recursion, constructor

I have a class which makes nested grouping. Simplified form is as follows.

```
public class Group
{
    public readonly object Key;
    public readonly IEnumerable<Group> Groups;
    public readonly IEnumerable<DataRow> Drs;

    public Group(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList)
    {
        Key = key;

        if (columnList.Count == 0)
            Drs = source;
        else
        {
            string firstColumn = columnList.First();
            List<string> restOfColumns = columnList.Skip(1).ToList();

            Groups = source.GroupBy(dr => dr[firstColumn])
                           .Select(g => new Group(g.Key, g, restOfColumns));    
        }
    }
}
```

This is fine up to some point. But sometimes I need more properties(and methods) for this class. At the same time I don't want to add those properties to this class, as it will break the simplicity and most of the usages will not be interested with these properties. For this reason I try to inherit from this class.

```
public class SpecialGroup:Group
{
    public SpecialGroup(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList) 
                             : base(key, source, columnList)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But this time `SpecialGroup` is not being recursively generated(as expected). Only the first main group is `SpecialGroup` and nested groups are all `Group`.

Can I, with some way, inherit from `Group` and still have recursion for the new type?

(Without usage of extension methods please, as it will not differ from writing all methods in the `Group` class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the creation of group polymorphic. For example:

```
public class Group
{
    public readonly object Key;
    public readonly IEnumerable<Group> Groups;
    public readonly IEnumerable<DataRow> Drs;

    public Group(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList)
    {
        Key = key;

        if (columnList.Count == 0)
            Drs = source;
        else
        {
            string firstColumn = columnList.First();
            List<string> restOfColumns = columnList.Skip(1).ToList();

            Groups = source.GroupBy(dr => dr[firstColumn])
                           .Select(g => CreateGroup(g.Key, g, restOfColumns));    
        }
    }

    protected virtual Group CreateGroup(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList)
    {
        return new Group(key, source, columnList)
    }
}
```

And then in your `SpecialGroup` override it to return `SpecialGroup`.

```
public class SpecialGroup:Group
{
    public SpecialGroup(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList) 
                             : base(key, source, columnList)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }

    protected override Group CreateGroup(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList)
    {
        return new SpecialGroup(key, source, columnList)
    }
}
```

This way, if your root group is of type `SpecialGroup` its children will be of type `SpecialGroup`, otherwise `Group`.

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same thing, the only other change I would have done is make the public field `Groups` in to a read only property with a backing field, then in the inherited class shadow the property to be `new public  IEnumerable<SpecialGroup> Groups { get { return _groups.Cast<SpecialGroup>(); } }`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Where does that `_groups` comes from? If that's from base class then the cast will fail because `_groups` isn't `IEnumerable<SpecialGroup>` but `IEnumerable<Group>`

Comment: Refresh, I realized my mistake and corrected it. `_groups` is the protected backing field for the new read-only property.

Comment: Very good answer thank you. I will try to use nested groups as `SpecialGroup`. And thanks for useful comments @ScottChamberlain .

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer a slightly different solution, using generics. The problem is `C#` does not allow calling non default constructors for a generic type *T* so I have to resort to some reflection.

```
using System.Reflection;

public class Group<T> where T : Group<T>
{
    public readonly object Key;
    public readonly IEnumerable<T> Groups;
    public readonly IEnumerable<DataRow> Drs;

    public Group(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList)
    {
        Key=key;

        if(columnList.Count==0)
            Drs=source;
        else
        {
            string firstColumn=columnList.First();
            List<string> restOfColumns=columnList.Skip(1).ToList();

            Groups=source.GroupBy(dr => dr[firstColumn])
                           .Select(g => Factory(g.Key, g, restOfColumns));
        }
    }

    static ConstructorInfo ctor;    //store constructor for type T

    static T Factory(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList)
    {
        if(ctor==null)
        {
            // if constructor not found yet, assign it
            ctor=typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] {
            typeof(object),
            typeof(IEnumerable<DataRow>),
            typeof(List<string>)});

            if(ctor==null)
            {
                throw new MissingMethodException("Could not find appropriate constructor");
            }
        }
        // invoke constructor to create a new T
        return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { key, source, columnList }) as T;
    }
}

public class SpecialGroup : Group<SpecialGroup>
{
    public SpecialGroup(object key, IEnumerable<DataRow> source, List<string> columnList)
        : base(key, source, columnList) { }
    void DoSomething() { }
}
```

NOTE that you cannot create an instance of `Group<T>` anymore. For a base class you need to define `class BaseGroup : Group<BaseGroup> { }` just like `SpecialGroup` but with no additional methods.

Comment: Thanks for the different approach. Even though I am avoiding reflection where there are other solutions, this gives me good example for the use of reflection.